# Are there any books similar to The Devils Deceptions (Talbis Iblis) by Ibn al-Jawzi

Tags: shaitan, books

I am reading this book `Devils Deceptions (Talbis Iblis)` from a very long time and already did a lot of search to find some other books similar to this one but unable to find one, can anybody recommend me anyother book similar to this or any islamic book related to `iblis`, `shaitan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the book of ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyyah ابن قيم الجوزبة:

> إغاثة اللهفان من مصايد الشيطان

> Ighathat-u al-Lahfaan min massaayidi a-Shaytan

But you'd better point at the topic you are looking for the information you've shared is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, my bad but thankyou for the answer!